# how to make custom animation growing Pie chart using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

there is one variant by this position (0deg, 90deg, 180deg, 360deg) but I need pie chart via random data(and degrees).
For example like this but again not only these fixed numbers (degrees).[like this post`const pieChart = ?`](https://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/y38q271f/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use parameters for the values. You can just wrap a function around the interval and **Presto**

There was some bug fixing that I've done but some remain. You wont get a full ripoff from [Kevin Faulhaber's](https://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/y38q271f/3/) code.

The method used here to draw the circle is [arc()](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp) and with some more work you should get along nicely. Hope this answers your question.

```js
var canv2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx2 = canv2.getContext("2d");

var r = 60,
    sAngle = 0,
    angle = 0,
    eAngle = 0;

function drawCircle(part0, part1, part2, part3) {
    var interval2 = setInterval(function () {


        if (angle == 0) {
            ctx2.beginPath();
            sAngle = -0.001;
        } else if (angle == part0) {
            ctx2.beginPath();
            sAngle = part0 * (Math.PI / 180);
            console.log(sAngle)
        } else if (angle == part1) {
            ctx2.beginPath();
            sAngle = part1 * (Math.PI / 180);
        } else if (angle == part2) {
            ctx2.beginPath();
            sAngle = part2 * (Math.PI / 180);
        } else if (angle == part3) {
            ctx2.beginPath();
            sAngle = part3 * (Math.PI / 180);
        } else {
            if (angle > 0 && angle <= part0) {
                ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle + .02);
                ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
                ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
                ctx2.fill();
            } else if (angle > part0 && angle <= part1) {
                ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle + .02);
                ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
                ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
                ctx2.fill();
            } else if (angle > part1 && angle <= part2) {
                ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle + .02);
                ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
                ctx2.fillStyle = "orange";
                ctx2.fill();
            } else if (angle > part2 && angle <= part3) {
                ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle + .02);
                ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
                ctx2.fillStyle = "blue";
                ctx2.fill();
            } else if (angle > part3 && angle <= 360) {
                ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle + .02);
                ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
                ctx2.fillStyle = "violet";
                ctx2.fill();
            } else {
                console.log(angle)
                clearInterval(interval2);
            }
        }

        angle++;
        eAngle = angle * (Math.PI / 180);

    }, 10);
}

drawCircle(60, 120, 220, 270);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks so much. but is there some way to fix the issue of this circle, I mean the clearing of it cause of as I see this circle's lines isn't clear right?

Comment: That's some thing that can happen if you try to draw a circle with squares. Try to make it bigger or smaller, there should be a sweet spot